# Android chat app that lets me chat via 2+ Yahoo IM accounts

Tags: android, chat

Looking for Android chat app that lets me chat via 2+ Yahoo IM accounts.

Motivation: I used IMO for this, and they are [discontinuing their support for 3rd party chat](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2014/03/01/imo-discontinue-support-third-party-messaging-services-march-3-focus-platform/). Frankly, IMO's features were "good enough".

Requirements:

- Lets me connect to multiple (or at least 2 :) different Yahoo IM accounts simultaneously
- Remembers userIDs and passwords permanently
- Notifications on incoming messages (configurable to be sound/buzz; ideally different sounds per account)
- Notifications if a given IM account is disconnected due to being logged in elsewhere (Yahoo only lets 1 client to connect at a time, unlike Hangouts)
- IMPORTANT: Decent power consumption. This can be measured by lack of reviews citing that the app is a power drain on even a modern cell phone, or better yet a review citing that it is not.
- Similarly, is not known to be resource hog in other ways.
- Fast (e.g. doesn't have 15 minute lag to deliver chat messages) - ideally, realtime push.
- Ideally, can be started when the phone starts (via Intent :)
- Ideally, persists chat history locally.